# Laravel parallel test cant create the database

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am trying to run laravel feature tests in parallel mode as it is in document. My `phpunit.xml` is configed as below :

```
<php>
   <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
   <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
   <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
   <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
   <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
   <env name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
   <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>
</php>
```

and I am running the tests with this command :

```
php artisan test --parallel
```

The result is all tests fail with this error message :

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'mydbname_test_11'
```

should I create this database before starting test or laravel creates that automatically ?

Comment: Laravel doesn't create databases automatically. You'd need to create the database beforehand. I don't think you can even do it in a migration because migrations require the migration table to exist and that needs to be in the database

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the database must exist before you run your test. another thing to note is that parallel unlike PHP artisan test, will not migrate your database for you. So what I found works best is to migrate my database before running the test in parallel.

Comment: sorry do you mean i must create for example shop_test_1 && shop_test_2 and like this 10 dbs ?

Comment: @Farshad unfortunately yes! You need to create those databases in advance. :(

Comment: @Charles do you have an example of doing this in bitbucket pipelines or a similar deploy environment?

Comment: @DrewGallagher When i did this i would run php artisan migrate on the test db and then i would run the parallel command because it takes a snapshot of the db so something like 

- php artisan migrate --force 
- php artisan test. --parallel

Answer (score 2):

**You do not need to manually create databases to run tests in parallel.** Laravel will create these databases for you automatically and tear them down when your tests have finished.

This is true also when running in Bitbucket Pipelines, for the commenter that asked.

From the [documentation on parallel testing in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/testing#parallel-testing-and-databases) (9.x):

> As long as you have configured a primary database connection, Laravel automatically handles creating and migrating a test database for each parallel process that is running your tests. The test databases will be suffixed with a process token which is unique per process. For example, if you have two parallel test processes, Laravel will create and use your_db_test_1 and your_db_test_2 test databases.

Your issue is likely to be a composer dependency that is preventing Laravel from creating these databases. In my case, it was the `grimzby/laravel-mysql-spatial` package. [Link to the relevant issue here](https://github.com/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial/issues/169).

Comment: @HashimAziz This is true, I've linked to the docs which explicitly states it creates parallel testing databases for you. You also don't need another dependency for parallel testing, I never stated this. But yes, as mentioned in the documentation, a primary database needs to be configured. The issue in question is that the additional databases needed to run tests in parallel don't seem to be created, *not* the primary database. This is a different issue that you're talking about

Answer (score 0):

When running tests in parallel mode with Laravel, it is necessary to create a separate database for each parallel test process. Laravel will not create these databases automatically, so it is up to you to ensure that they exist before running your tests. You can either create the databases manually, or you can use a tool like PHPUnit's `@database` annotations to automatically create and tear down the necessary databases before and after each test run.

In your `phpunit.xml` file, you can specify the `DB_DATABASE` and `DB_USERNAME` environment variables to control which database Laravel should use for testing. For example:

```
<php>
   <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
   <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
   <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
   <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
   <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
   <env name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
   <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>
   <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="mydbname_test_%s"/>
   <env name="DB_USERNAME" value="myusername"/>
</php>
```

The `%s` in the `DB_DATABASE` value will be replaced with the current test process number, so each test process will use a different database. You will need to make sure that a database with the appropriate name exists for each test process before running your tests.

You can then use the `@database` annotation in your test classes to control the creation and destruction of these databases.